# PHP Get part of a string with slashes

Tags: php

My website is like ?dir=/friends/pending and i was wondering if i could get just the "friends" part of the string?

My attempt so far

```
//I got the "pending" part by below...
$val = substr( $_GET['a'], strrpos( $_GET['a'], '/' )+1 );

//I tried getting "friends" with this but it didnt give me what i wanted..
$val2 = substr( $_GET['a'], strrpos( $_GET['a'], '/' )- $val -2 );
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use PHP's `explode`:

```
$pieces = explode('/', $_GET['a']);

# $pieces[1] = 'friends'
```

See the documentation: http://www.php.net/explode